# How to display a PDF in iframe with ajax after calling a servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf, iframe

I have a problem when I want to display a PDF in an iframe (using the attribute src).The PDF is never downloaded from the browser.
I need to use an ajax call to display a message in a popup in some cases.
The code of the servlet that generate the PDF works because currently we use this directly in the src attribute of the iframe.

```
 <iframe src="myServlet" />
```

But when I use the servlet with a ajax call, and I want to add the content of the PDF in the iframe, it doesn't work.
I don't know why.
This is an example of the js :

```
$.ajax(
{
   url: "myServlet",
   ...
   complete: function(data) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        $('#myframe').attr("src", downloadUrl);
   }
 }
);
```

I try with chrome and I have the error: 
jquery-2.1.3.js?ts=13012017:3 GET data:application/pdf;base64,blob:http://localhost:8180/d21d82b6-8254-4a38-907e-129b3ac037fa net::ERR_INVALID_URL

I can see that I have the data as a binary file:
%PDF-1.4
%����
3 0 obj
<>stream
x��{PU��^A��e�(�......................
...................
startxref
38448
%%EOF

Sorry but I don't have the code here (at home), but I think that the explanations are fairly clear.
I don't know why the PDF cannot be downloaded if I use ajax with iframe and attribut src.
Do you have an idea?

Thanks.
Fred

Answer (score 2):

This do the trick for me.

```
$.ajax(
{
   url: "myServlet",
   ...
   complete: function(data) {
        $('#myframe').attr('src','data:application/pdf;base64,'+data);
   }
 }
);
```

Also, you should encode the ajax ans this way `base64_encode($data)`.

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, to encode the ajax answer you should do it this way:

```
var enc = btoa(data)
```

If you have problems, you should try this:

```
var enc = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)))
```

Then

```
 $('#myframe').attr('src','data:application/pdf;base64,'+ enc);
```